# How to do interactive MathML with React?

Tags: reactjs, mathml

Writing a math expression as text can make it quite ugly

```
<p>λy.xy</p>
```

results in this: [image: unicode lambda expression]

Doing it with MathML seems better

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi>&lambda;</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
    <mo>.</mo>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
</math>
```

gives: [image: MathML lambda expression]

(On math stack exchange it's even nicer with the same MathML: [image: lambda expression from math stack exchange], but I'm not sure yet how to get that without MathJax)

I want to have the nicer look in my React app, but it doesn't seem to accept the `<math>` tag. Is there a solution that would be similar to JSX and let me use React interactivity like the HTML below?

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mi onClick="console.log('hello')">&lambda;</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
    <mo>.</mo>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
</math>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math) element appears to be perfectly valid HTML, which means it should work just fine in JSX in React as well. The only issue I see in your JSX is with the `mi` element's `onClick` handler. You've specified a string value when it should be a function in JSX, e.g. change `onClick="console.log('hello')"` to `onClick={() => console.log('hello')}`.

Example:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mi onClick={() => console.log('hello')}>&lambda;</mi>
        <mi>y</mi>
        <mo>.</mo>
        <mi>x</mi>
        <mi>y</mi>
      </math>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: it does, actually work, thanks! The onclick string was an example. I thought it didn't work because typescript errors ("Property 'math' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'"), but it does run. Do you know how to get rid of the typescript error?

Comment: works with ```declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      math: any;
      mi: any;
      mo: any;
    }
  }
}```